# Disable Number Pad in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

This question refers to a desktop computer.  Is there a way to disable the number pad under windows 7?  Alternatively, is there a way to disable certain keys?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to disable the numpad? More specifically, do you want to force `NumLock` be stay in one state (On/Off), or disable the keys entirely? This is also a bit of a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what you actually need might not be disabling the numpad.

Comment: I want to disable the numpad completely.  I use a trackball mouse and if I can put it on top of the numpad, it would make my workstation more comfortable.  I have a very flat keyboard.

Comment: I think you may have hit one of the very few real reasons to disable a desktop numpad. If no one else has answered, I'll look in to an Autohotkey solution tomorrow morning, when I actually have a desktop keyboard to test with ;)

Comment: You can use a hammer to break the keys or to pull them off, or a ripper to split numpad and the rest of kb. You can also use glue and some papers to isolate that area on keyboard (label it as "no trepassing"). Or you can simply buy a keyboard without numpad.

Answer (score 6):

You can disable the numpad completely through [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). You can set Autohotkey scripts to [run on startup](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup). You can also [compile the script to a standalone executable](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) if you do not wish to keep Autohotkey installed. This script will cause all standard numpad buttons to do nothing:

```
*NumLock::
*Numpad0::
*Numpad1::
*Numpad2::
*Numpad3::
*Numpad4::
*Numpad5::
*Numpad6::
*Numpad7::
*Numpad8::
*Numpad9::
*NumpadDot::
*NumpadDiv::
*NumpadMult::
*NumpadAdd::
*NumpadSub::
*NumpadEnter::
*NumpadIns::
*NumpadEnd::
*NumpadDown::
*NumpadPgDn::
*NumpadLeft::
*NumpadClear::
*NumpadRight::
*NumpadHome::
*NumpadUp::
*NumpadPgUp::
*NumpadDel::
Return
```

Each hotkey carries on to the next, because nothing is assigned to them, until it reaches the `Return`, which causes the hotkey to end - and since nothing has been done so far, nothing happens. A drawback of this approach is that virtual keypresses would be blocked too; the script could be modified to confirm it's only blocking the physical keypress if necessary, but that's a fair bit of work, so unless you need it...

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an elegant on inelegant solution to the issue... ;p

Comment: Well, it does *work*. If necessary, it's even possible to assign a hotkey to toggle (enable/disable) the keys, so it's also quite versatile ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work but u can give a try.

First link is freeware software. On second URL u can find settings for registry in Windows Vista.

1. [Set or Unset NUM LOCK in Windows Freeware](http://www.somacon.com/p339.php)
2. [How to Enable or Disable a Toggle Key at Startup in Vista](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/91086-toggle-keys-startup.html)

Comment: It might help to say what these links *actually are*

Answer (score 0):

This program allows you to map/unmap keys to different functions
[Scancode Mapper](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/Posts/Details/12420) including diabling keys entirely. I've used it to map caps lock to be a shift key, but it can disable keys by mapping them to none.

It's actually a wrapper to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout` registry key. if you look at [Microsoft's explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463447.aspx) of the key, you will see why the wrapper program is useful

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it for software easily with a software, but not for hardware:

- You must remove trackball from the top of numpad everytime you boot the computer (you would hear a lot of beeps or enter the BIOS config if trackball is in top of "del" key);
- Inside SO, you can have some problems pressing some keys because a lot of keys are pressed at same time (well, just press 4 or more keys at same time and try to use your computer).

You can solve that completely only if you:

Recommended:

- Buy a new keyboard without numpad;
- Buy a smaller keyboard that allow you to use trackball comfortably;
- Buy a keyboard with a trackball;
- Use a creative solution, like an "elevated mousepad" to do not touch the keys on numpad (something like figure below).

[image: creative solution]

Not recomended:

- Change hardware of you keyboard to allow you to put that trackball on top of it (e.g., opening it and cutting correct connections with scissors).

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses numpad for some feature "Mouse Pointer Controlling with Keyboard". That means if you want to control the mouse pointer with numpad ***it will disable your numpad*** for other reasons.

So just enable that feature and enjoy :-)

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/use-mouse-keys-to-move-the-mouse-pointer